# calculate force betwen two objects like angry birds game

Tags: unity, physics

I'm trying to make a game like angry birds. in the game materials break and destroy based on force they receive. really what is the right or best way to implement it in unity?

thank you for helping.

Comment: [p=mv](https://www.google.ch/search?q=p+%3D+mv) - Also, while very broad questions often get closed as being too broad, not even putting in the bare minimum effort to get basic capitalization right usually guarantees it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Unity collision handler, you can check [collision.Impulse](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-impulse.html) to get a vector representing the influence the bodies are imparting to each other to brake the movement / rebound away from one another.

The magnitude of this vector is a good measure of how "intense" the impact is.

It's measured in [Newton-seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_second), representing the instantaneous change in momentum of the body, so it incorporates both **velocity** (more drastic change in motion = more impulse) and **mass** (heavier objects = more impulse)

Comment: thank you. i think its the right answer. ill accept it after checking it